# Install specific version of python in a nfs path

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv, pyenv

Hi need to install a specific version of python in nfs path that will be shared across multiple systems.
Users in each systems need to activate using virtual env and use it.
How can we achieve it through pyenv, venv, virtual env etc

Comment: what about sharing a `.yml` file across all machines to install conda env using the file?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to build python virtual environments into a shared NFS folder.

You could use pyenv to get the versions you need to build your virtual environments. We build virtual environments outside of pyenv using the above command after activating the version of python using pyenv

- pyenv shell 3.9.15
- python -m venv /opt/shared/python/ve/py3915

users can activate that version using

- source /opt/shared/python/ve/py3915/bin/activate

You could then use the following shebang in your scripts

- #!/usr/bin/env /opt/shared/python/ve/py3915/bin/python

My team uses virtual environments like this for scripting projects. The scripts developed for a given project use the shebang method above to activate the specific virtualenv and run the script. For example we have the following virtual environments.

- /opt/shared/python/ve/ansible4
- /opt/shared/python/ve/acicobra
- /opt/shared/python/ve/py3915

Each project that uses one of the virtualenv has a requirements file in the source code that dictates what modules need to be installed for that project

We have a team account for the install of the virtual environments into the shared NFS mount. That way an individual user can use the virtualenv in scripts etc but needs to su to the team account to add packages etc. The requirements file is in the project folder but the virtualenv is not in source control.